# Position Range in specific page to create a Table

Tags: c#, ms-word, range, interop

I'm trying to put a table in the specific place of a second page in my word document, but always get an error. I have the range in my database, it starts with 1049 and ends at 1420.

When I put those values I receive an `Out of Range Value` error. How can I put a table where I want?

This is a part of my code:

```
ApplicationClass wordApp = new ApplicationClass();
Document adoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref     missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table wordTable = null;

object rangeStart = null;
object rangeEnd = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngBold = null;

rangeStart = Int32.Parse(lstTables[1].RNG_STA.ToString()); // 0 - with zero works but    put in the beggining 
rangeEnd = Int32.Parse(lstTables[1].RNG_END.ToString()); // 0 - with zero works but put    in the beggining

rngBold = adoc.Range(ref rangeStart, ref rangeEnd);

wordTable = adoc.Tables.Add(rngBold, lstTables[1].TOTALLIN, lstTables[1].TOTALCOL, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: I think you need to make sure that that range actually exists in your document.

Comment: Thanks Thorias. I extract the information ranges from another document and keep them. Later i make a new document editing some data, but the positions must to be identycal. If that range actually not exists, how can i create the table where its must to be? Some idea?

Comment: I can't help you with that, sorry. You might have a look at [Word Object Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we.aspx) and start from there. Google has some links too.